# See if Azure Virtual Machine is down using python

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to write a python program that will alert me when a VM is down. I know PowerShell might be better but would prefer python.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it would be better with PowerShell :). Python rules ;)

If you want a more reactive programming, you should look at EventGrid + LogicApp + WebApp/Function first. It's like IFTTT for Azure, EventGrid will trigger an event, and LogicApp will be able to consume this event and send it to a WebApp or Function (that you can write in Python).
Example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app

If you want a more "I pull every minute" experience, just use the azure-mgmt-compute package:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-compute/

Basic sample:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage

You will need the instance view of the VM, to get the power state, with [instance_view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_10_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#instance-view-resource-group-name--vm-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-)

Hope this helps!

(I work at MS in the Azure SDK for Python team)

**EDIT:**

It seems EventGrid does not support trigger from VM power state yet, you could still use LogicApp with a poll schedule for solution 1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence